# Spanish National Team (Football) store in Madrid

Tags: spain, madrid, football

I will be visiting Madrid this summer (July), and would like to know if there's any store where I can buy official Spanish National football team products? Is there an Adidas store that sells them?

Comment: If you want an _official_ store, it would probably help to know _which team_ you're interested in.

Comment: Or do you mean the national team?

Comment: It is indeed about the National team. Question edited so it's more clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up the [official online store](http://www.tiendarfef.com/). The address given is C/ Ramón y Cajal, district Las Rozas. Google Maps shows a putative location for the shop, but Street View shows that there's nothing there. However, just to the north is the *[Museo de la Selección Española de Fútbol](http://www.sefutbol.com/museo-seleccion-espanola)* which probably has a gift shop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for Real Madrid, the first hit on Google points me to [this store location](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Real+madrid+store+madrid&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=40421337,-3691050,1154&tbm=lcl&rldimm=18288641071545012725&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e3!3sEAE,lf:1,lf_ui:3).